# Erro "trying to get property of non-object" ao usar ipinfo.io

Tags: php

Eu sou relativamente novo com **PHP** e comecei a mexer num site. E encontrei o seguinte código que estava a dar erro:

```
<?php        
 function ip_details() {
  $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/");
  $details = json_decode($json);
  return $details;
 }
 $details = ip_details();
 $ip = $details->ip;//34    
 $local = $details->city;  //35
?>
```

Este é o erro que me aparece:

> A PHP error was encountered
>   Severilty: Notice
>   Message: trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: views/login_view.php
>   Line Number: 34

Eu sei alguma coisa de **PHP** mas não entendi o que aqui estava e já tive à procura mas não encontrei nada que me fizesse entender o que era aquele código.

Alguém percebe este código que me saiba explicar?

Comment: Removi o "Boas" de sua pergunta, evite usa-lo.

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e rodou sem problemas, veja se o servidor onde está rodando tem suporte ao file_get_contents para endereços externos;

Comment: Você também pode dar um var_dump($details); para ver que conteúdo esta na variavel

Comment: Tentou colocar assim: `$json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/json");`?

Comment: Ao invés de postar perguntas como "o que isto faz", procure se concentrar no problema. No caso o problema seria com os dados trazidos pelo `file_get_contents` que não foram decodificados pelo `json_decode`. **E** não use imagens para ilustrar um erro que é uma mensagem em texto "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Outra coisa, me parece que o software está usando MVC, eu discordo de fazer execuções e tratamentos na camada View. Recomendo estudar MVC primeiro e usar a documentação PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bruno Gibellino,

essa script pega detalhes do ip,cidade,região,país, localização que pode ser usada para te encontrar no google maps por exemplo.

faça um teste, coloque um `echo` antes do `ip` e também no `$details->city`, vai mostrar o seu ip e onde você mora.